# M4 binary output

Tags: gnu, m4

Is it possible to define a M4 macro that outputs a binary integer? For example:

```
define(`foo', $1)
foo(42)
```

which should output 1 byte with a value of 42.

Answer (score 0):

```
define(`foo', `esyscmd(`python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write(chr($1))"')') dnl
foo(`42')
```

Expands to:

```
*
```

That's a bit of a cheat, though.

Answer (score 0):

In GNU m4 [there is a `format` macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/m4/Format.html) which is modeled after the C function `printf`.

```
% gm4
define(`chr', `format(`%c', `$1')')dnl
42 is chr(`42')
42 is *
```

This won't work in m4 that ships with FreeBSD.